# How to show less data labels but label for all data series in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I tried to show the data label for the current date only, and also to show data labels for all series (lines) even if some data value is 0%. I tried to use 0 label density but still get very messy looking - different series showed date labels in different dates, and at the end, not all the series had data value labeled. I noticed that someone recommended to create a new measure for current date for each line that could overlay the original chart, but it was not practical to us since we have 40+ charts and most the fields were created by complicated measures.

Is there any way to show less label density but also show labels for all series? OR, is there a way to show a legend table including the field value from the current date for those calculated measure? (Please note the example I attached was exported data value only that calculated by measures. If I show a table by picking up the measures from the current date, the measure will recalculate and the number will be wrong)
Please see attached example.
https://github.com/dgao95/Share-to-public/blob/main/Example%201%20Label%20issue.pbix

Thanks,
DG

Comment: which version of power bi are you using?

Comment: Version: 2.116.763.0 64-bit (April 2023). Thanks to look into it

Answer (score 0):

On power bi 2.116.622.0 version,
So the OP wants to show only the last value in the label for that we will create a new measure which will only have the last value in it
Note I have renamed the table name to `Fact` for easy understanding.

[image]

```
Line Label Measure = 
var max_label = CALCULATE(MAX(fact[cycle_date]), ALL(fact))

RETURN
IF(
    OR(
        MAX(fact[cycle_date]) = max_label,
        MIN(fact[cycle_date]) = min_label,
    ),
    SUM('fact'[A])
)
```

The same way you have to create rest of the measures (B-I)
Once created add it to the Y-Axis

[image]

Now you have to play around with the labels

1.First reset the Data labels to make sure no other settings is there

2.Turn off the label for only SUM of A

[image]

3.Now turn on the visual for newly added measure (Line label Measure)

[image]

This will add only the last data point for this measure,

[image]
You can update the same color for both measures to make it seamless.

[Source](https://datastud.dev/posts/power-bi-line-start-end-labels)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but I was required to have a cleaner version - as less density as possible, only show data labels for the last data point and for all series (that's why I set up density as 0%). Any further ideas in addition to the overlay idea?

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Yes, it works in a way to add the label for the last data point. But the issue we encountered now is the legend can't select to the line label or the field label only - so we will have double number of legend  (if we add them all) that in fact represent the same  measure - one is the line one is the dot of the last data point. Anyway to clean it further to show the last data label and also only show one legend, either the field serie name or the label measure? Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: I think the alternative perhaps to turn off the legend but turn on series name instead

Comment: @user21675773 , oh that's right let me check that